# jquery mobile not loading custom script in asp.net mvc4 SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

The script in question is app.js.

I have placed this custom script between jquery.min.js and jquery.mobile.js in the  section of _layout.Mobile.cshtml.

```
    @* one recommendation to load custom scripts but does not work *@
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   *@
    @*<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app.js?45")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/3rdparties")*@

    <script src=@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

I have also tried referencing the script immediately after the first  element with attribute role=page in Index.Mobile.cshtml.

```
<div data-role="page" id="agencies-pane">
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app.js?45")" rel="external" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div data-role="header" class="header"><h1><a>Agencies</a></h1></div>
```

In both cases, my custom script does not load.  What a waste of an entire afternoon :(

I do not want to disable Ajax even though I tried and failed at that miserably.  Can not seem to get anything jQM to work even after carefully reading instructions from [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not load"? Do you have 404 error in console? Or your `app.js` code does not get executed?

Comment: Looks like the code is not getting executed but what you've said here gave me some clues.  I have been trying to debug using Opera Mobile.  Chrome is reporting errors in my script, which may be the problem.    Thanks.

Comment: Now I feel like a dumb head.  My custom script is being loaded but there are errors all over the place as it was not designed with mobile in mind. Script is failing silently so it looks like it is not being loaded.